# Looking for GeoPandas equivalents of PostGIS "ST_DumpRings" and "ST_Dump" tools

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas DataFrame with a MultiPolygon geometry that I want to explode into separate line polygons. I do this by using:

```py
gdf.explode()
```

I believe this equates to PostGIS's [`ST_Dump()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) but i would like to do a [`ST_DumpRings()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpRings.html) also.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume there is a polygon, see the image below.

[image: input]

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

exterior = [(2, 8), (7, 8), (7, 3), (2, 3), (2, 8)]
interior = [(4, 7), (4, 5), (6, 5), (6, 7), (4, 7)]
interior2 = [(3, 5), (3, 4), (4, 4), (4, 5), (3, 5)]

poly = Polygon(exterior, holes=[interior, interior2])
```

Use either:

- [`.interiors`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.interiors.html):

  > Returns a Series of List representing the inner rings of each polygon
  > in the GeoSeries.

  ```py
   interiors = list(poly.interiors)
   for i, interior in enumerate(interiors):
       print(i, interior)

   #0 LINEARRING (4 7, 4 5, 6 5, 6 7, 4 7)
   #1 LINEARRING (3 5, 3 4, 4 4, 4 5, 3 5)
  ```

  [image: result_1]
- [`.exterior`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.exterior.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.exterior)

  > Returns a GeoSeries of LinearRings representing the outer boundary of
  > each polygon in the GeoSeries.

  ```
   <!-- language: python -->

   exterior = poly.exterior
   print(exterior)

   #LINEARRING (2 8, 7 8, 7 3, 2 3, 2 8)
  ```

  [image: result_2]

Both of the results are of the [`LinearRing`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linearrings) class type.